# Generated file for FragmentDirections doesn't have the same package name

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I have changed my android app's package name, after clean build and then build I got an error saying : Unresolved reference: `data` in a generated file (please see the picture below).

I have checked that this file doesn't have the same package name, there is a missing "com" at the beginning (line 1). Also at line 8, there also a missing "com" at the beginning.
I have been struggling with this issue without any luck to find a solution.

Thank you so much
[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv4Di.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

As I mentioned, a generated file was preventing me from building the project after package name refactor even after cleaning and then rebuilding it. I realised that this file has something to do with the navigation graph. So, I opened that file and searched for any leftovers from the previous package name and found it!
The refactoring process didn't refactor it all. I changed that and rebuilt the project and all went well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the old version of the navigation library which does not read from the namespace specified in the build.gradle file in app module.

I had to keep the namespace in the manifest file until I upgrade the navigation library.

AndroidManifest.xml looks like this now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.packagename">
```